# What's the integral of sec^2(x/2)tan(x/2)dx?

Tags: calculus

I want to know if I solved this integral correctly,

$$\int\sec^2\Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big) \tan \Big(\frac{x}{2}\Big)dx$$

I set $u = \tan\left(\frac x2\right)$, so $du = \frac12\sec^2\left(\frac x2\right)dx$.

My answer is $\tan\left(\frac x2\right)+c$, but the answers you got me a little confused.

Sorry, my English is very poor

Thanks.

Comment: What's the derivative of $\tan x$?

Comment: It's important to look into the problem thoroughly before coming here. And also show what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting $u=tan(x/2)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int \sec^2\frac x2 \tan \frac x2 dx= \int \frac{\sin \frac x2 dx}{ sin^2\frac x2 \cos \frac x2}=\int \frac{dx}{ sin\frac x2 \cos \frac x2}=2\int \frac{dx}{ sin x}=2\int \frac{\sin xdx}{ 1-\cos^2 x}=-2\int \frac{d(\cos x)}{ 1-\cos^2 x}$